# How to recover deleted file from mtp device?

Tags: android, data-recovery, mtp

Acidentally I deleted two directories of images from the internal stockage memory of my Asus zenfone MAX 3 and I don't have an SD card on it. I found [foremost](https://www.faclic.com/comment-recuperer-fichiers-supprimes-sous-ubuntu-12587.html) is a tool to recover deleted data. But it's not able to give it the `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C0` as a partition to scan it.
 I active the `USB debug` option following these instructions:

1. Go to Settings -> About Phone/Tablet.
2. Go to “Build Number” at the end of the Scroll list.
3. Tap on “Build Number” repeatedly 3 times
4. Now Developer Option will be included in setting list of yours now.
       Go to “Develop Options” to check USB debugging > OK. Done.

But in USB configuration I have:

1. Load
2. MTP(Media Transfer Protocol)
3. PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol)
4. RNDIS (USB Ethernet)
5. Audio Source
6. MIDI

I plug the usb cable to the pc and I got this alert message:

```
 Use USB to transfer files
```

I pressed `OK`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which mtp device you have but I have been able to recover files using **photorec** (part of the package testdisk) where scapel (outdated) and foremost (also outdated) were not able to. I also recommend setting the mtp device to mass storage so photorec can read it as mentioned here [How to mount Smartphone to recover files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446180/how-to-mount-smartphone-to-recover-files)

Comment: I run `photorec` but I didn't find the device in the list of devices.

Comment: Follow the link provided about setting it up as a mass storage. Also mention in your post what storsge device you are using and what you have done so far to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't - because MTP is a high level protocol. It doesn't give you access to the underlying file system; it gives you access to the filesystem as seen by the system hosting the MTP session (e.g. phone in this example). The systems sees the files as deleted, so it's not accessible over MTP.

You need to gain access to this device somehow. Some phones can show up as mass storage devices, and if it's a SD card you can pop this into your computer. Or you can find a recovery tool that runs at the phone.

Comment: I tried to use `USB DEBUG` option and then I used `photorec` but the device is not displayed in the list.

Comment: USB Debugging on Android is not for giving raw block-level access to the flash of the phone. It's a debugging API.

Comment: So it's not able to recover data from linux?

Comment: Not over MTP or USB debugging, no. You have to get a image or raw block-level access. Read and understand [the naswer by Oli](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446180/how-to-mount-smartphone-to-recover-files) on that Q&A.

Comment: I have already read it and I followed the first part of the answer and It does not resolve my problem.