# How to mount MTP like a drive in /dev?

Tags: usb, mount, android, disk, mtp

I am trying to recover some files on my android device, but without success. So I would like to try tools like photorec, but they need a physically mounted device.
Or rather, for the moment photorec makes me recover files only from /dev/sdx, so I need to mount the mtp device like this.
For now I have tried this solution here:
[How to mount Smartphone to recover files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446180/how-to-mount-smartphone-to-recover-files)
but jmtpfs gives me an error.

Comment: Remember that an Android device is NOT a simple hard drive. It's a fully-functional, powerful computer *pretending* to be a simple hard drive by exposing the MTP API. Access to storage is provided by Android OS, and cannot be bypassed unless you physically remove the actual storage and plug it into different hardware. If Android MTP refuses to cooperate, not much Ubuntu can do about it. Note the top-voted answer in your link already told you this.

Comment: Modern android talks in MTP. Old ones could be mounted as mass storage. See if your device has the option to mount as mass storage from developer option or the notification shown after connecting it to computer.

Comment: Cross-posted to Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241778/44325